# InAppBrowser (Apache cordova plugin) does not open in Windows 8.1

Tags: cordova, windows-8.1, cordova-plugins, visual-studio-cordova, inappbrowser

I am developing an app using visual studio tools for apache Cordova (Cordova CLI : 4.3.1) and AngularJS.

It uses InAppBrowser plugin via ngcordova library. 
Here is my code:

```
 var url = "http://myurl.com";
 var target = "_blank";
 var options = {
            location: 'no',
            toolbar:'no',
            hidden: 'no'
        };

 document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {

            var browserRef = $cordovaInAppBrowser.open(url, target, options).then(function (event) {
            }, function (error) {
                console.log("Error: " + error.message);
            });

        }, false);
```

When i deploy the app on windows 8.1 (on my local machine), i can see on debugger that a webview is created without error, and loadstop event is fired. but it is not displayed, i can't see the external page.

It is working fine on iOS. I cannot try on android for now.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

can you try replacing

```
$cordovaInAppBrowser.open(.........
```

With

```
window.open(..........
```

Comment: I tried, it is exactly the same behavior... The webView is created in VS debugger but not displayed. 
Javascript console indicates : html1300 navigation occurred  login.php

Comment: ok can you refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31215572/cordova-load-remote-site-into-app/31241103#31241103