# Cordova Load Remote Site into App

Tags: cordova, webview

I have a website that I've coded with jQuery and HTML5. I'd like to use a simple framework for IOS and Android that loads my website into the app - essentially an internal browser. Clicking on a link in the app would go to to that remote page inside the app.

I've tried setting a location on index.html using Cordova but it's loading the external site into the device browser and not the app:

```
<html lang="us">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false); 
        function onDeviceReady() {
            // Now safe to use the Codova API
            window.location="http://www.test.com"; 
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

**How can I load my remote site with Cordova so the app is essentially a web browser? Is there a better/easier solution other than Cordova to accompolish this?**

Comment: Did you check inAppBrowser of Phonegap? http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Install In App browser

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
```

then in the code

```
var options = {
      location: 'yes',
      clearcache: 'yes',
      toolbar: 'no'
    };



$cordovaInAppBrowser.open('http://yoururlhere.com', '_blank', options)
```

For more details refer [cordova in App Browser documentation](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/inAppBrowser/)